# Patches after updating to ESX 4 U1

Tags: vmware-server

I have one server with ESX 4 U1 installed through downloaded dvd from Vmware site. How do I know what patches I need to install?
When I check the Patch Repository, i see that the release date for the update is Dec.9,2009.

1. Does it mean that I don't need any patches before that date?
2. Should I install all the patches after the release date?

Thanks,

Haim Beyhan

Answer (score 1):

Install the VMClient utility onto a windows box. Pick the option to install the Host Update program. After the installation has completed, login to your server using the client to validate your connection. The close the app and start the Host Update application, it will want the name/address of your server as well as your username and password. Then you can add/select the link for your server and pick check/look for updates. If there are updates, it will give you a list. The only catch you might run into is that you might have to put the server in "maintenance mode" before you apply the patches.